# SQL - How to get percentage of SUM

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make  stored procedure where i can get the company name and the sum of the workforce (number of employees), then finally the percentage of entire workforce that works for that company.I'm getting stuck trying to do the division. You can submit your code as pure sql, but I'm doing this in a java program. Im trying to do the logic all in sql, but I can do it in java if need be.

```
SELECT SUM(COMPANY_WORKFORCE) AS totalWorkforce FROM COMPANIES WHERE COMPANY = 'USAPaper';
```

Divide by

```
SELECT SUM(COMPANY_WORKFORCE) FROM COMPANIES;
```

Update

How do i specify which company to display. I just want the percentage of workforce USA paper has compared to the the entire workforce of all the companies

```
SELECT CITY, COMPANY,  COMPANY_WORKFORCE, COMPANY_WORKFORCE * 100 / t.s AS `% of total` FROM COMPANIES CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(COMPANY_WORKFORCE) AS s FROM COMPANIES) t
```

Comment: Why use a sproc? And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `filter` to `SUM` aggregate and divide it by total sum

Try this way

```
SELECT Sum(CASE
             WHEN COMPANY = 'USAPaper' THEN COMPANY_WORKFORCE
             ELSE 0
           END) / NULLIF(Sum(COMPANY_WORKFORCE), 0)
FROM   COMPANIES
```

Used `NULLIF` in denominator to handle divided by zero error.

Comment: what if sum of company and and workforce is 0?

Comment: @shreyanshjogi - Did you see the `NULLIF` in denominator. Answer will be `NULL`

Comment: my bad i have not observed. yes that works

Comment: @Prdp I couldn't get yours to work. The other answer linked to my question is basically what i want to do, im just trying to now figure out how to specify that i just want the one company to display.